# Device token not being set

Tags: mixpanel, segment-io

Has anyone ever had a problem using Segment analytics SDK integrated with Mixpanel (cloud settings only, no Mixpanel SDK integrated)?

I'm registering the device token for push notification using the code:

```
SEGAnalytics.shared().registeredForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken: deviceToken)
```

...but we have almost half the users with a `Ios devices` key set in Mixpanel but no value, just an empty string.
There's no pattern among the users in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

An empty 'iOS Devices' property on your People profiles generally indicates that there's a mismatch between the device token and the app's SSL push certificate that's been saved in your Mixpanel project; or, it could simply be an improperly formatted device token.

The fact that the property has been set in the first place means that you have successfully sent the device token to Mixpanel, however Mixpanel will remove tokens when their is a mismatch.

Mixpanel has a help doc that answers this specific question: https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-does-mixpanel-manage-push-tokens-when-they-are-invalid-or-when-the-app-has-been-uninstalled.

Likewise, Segment has documentation for supporting mixpanel Push notifications here: https://segment.com/docs/integrations/mixpanel/#push-notifications.